# changing values inside the alertdialog using showDialog without user interaction

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-storage

My problem is that the dialog box does not change the texts based on the counter of my `List<dynamic> getDownloadUrls`. I want to show how many images has been uploaded out of the images that the user selected to be uploaded.

These are my `List` variables

```
// List for Image Picker
  List<XFile>? imageFileList = [];
// List of upload images that is converted to URLs
  List<dynamic> getDownloadUrls = [];
```

here is the code for the submit button in the last stepper:

```
onPressed: () {
// last step of the stepper
// if at last step, the imageS should be able to be uploaded in firebase storage
// and then send the URLS to cloud firestore.
    final isLastStep = currentStep == getSteps().length - 1;
          if (isLastStep) {
//here is the function for both showDialog and uploading of images.
              uploadImageWithAlertDialog();
             } else {
              setState(() {
               currentStep += 1;
             });
            }
        },
```

and this is my upload images function which is totally working fine now.

```
Future uploadImage() async {
    String catchUrls;
    // loop, reiterate the files stored in List<XFile> imageFileList
    for (var image in imageFileList!) {
      // create new file name
      String uniqueFileName = DateTime.now().microsecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      // get current file name
      String currentFileName = image.path;
      // replace with new file na,e
      String newFileName =
          currentFileName.replaceAll(currentFileName, uniqueFileName);
      // reference the location of file.
      Reference reference =
          FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child("images").child(newFileName);
      // upload file
      await reference.putFile(File(image.path));
      // get the download urls
      catchUrls = await reference.getDownloadURL();
      // store the download urls to the List<String>getDownloadUrls.
      getDownloadUrls.add(catchUrls);
    }
  }
```

here is the `uploadImageWithAlertDialog` function

```
uploadImageWithAlertDialog() {
    Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 1000), () {
      // Your code
      uploadImage();
    });
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
// in the message, I want to update it based on how many images has been uploaded
// how many urls have been fetched in the list string
        return CustomAlertDialog(
          message:
              "uploading ${getDownloadUrls.length} out of ${imageFileList!.length}",
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

and I am using a `CustomAlertDialog` Stateless Widget so I am just calling it inside the `showDialog`

```
class CustomAlertDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  final String? message;
  // final VoidCallbackAction? onPress;

  const CustomAlertDialog({
    super.key,
    this.message,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2, sigmaY: 2),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 48.0),
          child: StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
            return AlertDialog(
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
              contentPadding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40, right: 40, top: 20),
              actionsPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, bottom: 30),
              actionsAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              content: Text(message!,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                      fontSize: 16,
                      color: Colors.black)),
            );
          }),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```